# Identify LOC for each file in iOS project - ObjectiveC based application development

Tags: objective-c, ios, lines-of-code, cloc

Is there tool that will give me a detailed report on number lines each file/class in project has?

I tried CLOC. All that I get is that the project level and that is nice to start with. I want a detailed drill down on each class. Do we have any open source tools that will do this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Xcode Assistant...

[Download here...](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/22611/xcode-assistant)

Comment: Great. Can I execute it from a command line. I'll need it for my build process

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [sloccount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/), you will get the LOC by directories and files as expected. You won't be able to have the LOC by class however.

If this limitation is ok, just use the `--details` flag in the command line you are using, for example if you run the sloccount command in the root directory of your Xcode project::

```
    sloccount --duplicates --wide --details YOUR-TARGET-NAME
```

The output is a bit hard to read but you will get all the information you need.

If you want to have a nice report and be able to drill down in the directories/files via a HTML report, I suggest using Jenkins. Just install the 'Jenkins plugin for sloccount' via Jenkins UI.

You can see how to setup it in this [blog article](http://blog.octo.com/en/jenkins-quality-dashboard-ios-development/#step1-1) (disclaimer: I am the author). You will also be able to see examples of such reports.

Answer (score 0):

i was looking for a good open source metrics counter for Objective C for a long time... i didn't find any yet...

you can use ProjectCodeMeter http://projectcodemeter.com, but it's not free... hovever the trial version works for 3 months and when it ran out i installed it on my laptop and got another 3 months :)

Answer (score 0):

I only find Xcode Statistician at http://www.literatureandlatte.com/freestuff/index.html